# How to display header image in WooCommerce pages with Genesis child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

We're using a custom child theme of Genesis, and the custom header image is not displaying.

Child Theme's `woocommerce.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Template
 * 
 * Template used for all WooCommerce views for your site
 *
 */

//* Remove standard post content output
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');

//* Add WooCommerce content output
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'woocommerce_setup_genesis' );

genesis();
```

Child Theme's `functions.php`:

```
/* WooCommerce */

function woocommerce_setup_genesis() {
  woocommerce_content();
}
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

I was hoping to learn the custom code to allow header images to work with WooCommerce.

Help appreciated.

Comment: What header images? Can you please explain, where header images are being stored, then you can add those into the Genesis hook...

Answer (score 0):

Tested on the Genesis Sample child theme with WooCommerce, header images display in the header by default. There's no need to add or edit code.

Go to the customizer and add your header image.

Here's the header image in blue showing on the Cart page

[image]